# Adding a 'Datetime' object to a time delta

Tags: python, datetime, swagger

I'm new to python, and I'm trying to do some math on dates. The starting date is pulled from a  swagger interface that can be found here: 
https://esi.tech.ccp.is/latest/#!/Market/get_markets_region_id_orders

The relevant field is the "issued" field. Currently I'm trying to add to that using a timedelta like this:

`date = market_ops.data[i].issued
completion_date = date + datetime.timedelta(days=int(market_ops.data[i].duration))`

This returns the error: `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Datetime' and 'datetime.timedelta'`

Does this mean the "issued" object is not a datetime.datetime object, but some other type of object, or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: It does indeed sound like you don't have a `datetime.datetime` but something else named `Datetime`.

Comment: Is there a way for me to inspect that object somehow? Searching for `python 'Datetime'` is just as useless as would be expected in this case.

Comment: You could try `help(date)` to see if that gives you any clues.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to convert the string data into a `datetime.datetime` instance before adding the `datetime.timedelta` to it.

Something along these lines:

```
date_string = market_ops.data[i].issued
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string[:10], '%Y-%m-%M')
completion_date = date + datetime.timedelta(days=int(market_ops.data[i].duration))
```

Note that the result in the calculated `completion_date` will also be of type `datetime.datetime`.

Comment: You're right, that's pretty much what I ended up doing. I was just about to come share my solution

Answer (score 0):

As @martineau suggested below, I just needed to stringify the 'Datetime' object, which is a swagger primitive, and then `strptime()` the resulting string as such:

```
start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(market_ops.data[i].issued)[0:19],
                                              '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S') 
completion_date = start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=int(market_ops.data[i].duration))
```